# What does a matrix array look like for a Johnson graph?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, graph-theory, combinatorics, adjacency-matrix

I can't seem to find any examples (or much information at all) of what a matrix array looks like for a Johnson graph. Can anyone send me an example of what their arrays look like?

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JohnsonGraph.html what you are thinking of? If so and if you gave a sample set S and and if you gave a couple of the J(n,k) that might be interesting to you then someone might be able to write a couple lines of code to produce the matricies for you. The wiki says the J(n,1) are boring, but for modest n,k it might be possible to see something informative. Describing exactly how you want the information presented would be essential.

Comment: @Bill any random Johnson graph matrix would do fine. I just want to see how it the layout looks for such graphs.

Comment: @Bill I would just like to analyze and compare with regular types of graphs so that I can see the differences in their matrix arrays. I cannot find an example of any Johnson graph in matrix form. That's why I am asking.

Comment: "what a matrix array looks like"  ?? This is completely unclear what you even mean by that. Are you aware of the rich set of graph theory tools built into mathematica? Do you mean adjacency matrix?

Comment: @Bill Yes adjacency matrix of any random Johnson graph please. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directly uses the definition of a Johnson Graph given here [Wiki Johnson Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph)

```
johnsonmatrix[n_, k_] := Module[{s=Select[Subsets[Range[n]], Length[#]==k&]},
  {s, MatrixForm[Table[If[Length[Intersection[s[[i]], s[[j]]]]==k-1, 1, 0],
  {i, Length[s]}, {j, Length[s]}]]}]
```

and generates the list of subsets which index the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix followed by the adjacency matrix for the graph.

For example, the first few `johnsonmatrix[n,1]` generate the complete graphs with n verticies and `johnsonmatrix[5, 2]` matches the number of verticies and edges given in the example graph in the upper right corner of that wiki page and every vertex has six incident edges. But I haven't manually checked to make absolutely certain that this matrix is isomorphic to the graph shown.

Please check this carefully to try to make certain that no errors have slipped in.

Comment: I'm not able to produce a matrix using your code. Do I need to alter anything in there? I just copy pasted it in Mathematica then hit shift+enter. Sorry for being such a beginner. if you can produce any matrix and add it to your answer that would be best!

Comment: @justinpees After copying and evaluating (shift+enter) the definition for `johnsonmatrix[n_, k_]` you should also evaluate this function with some values of its arguments, for example `johnsonmatrix[5, 2]` (copy, paste and also press shift+enter).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I could have sworn I tried that. Thanks for clarifying, I'm able to see it now!!!