# What symbols are used to express an empty cell in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, latex, wolfram-mathematica, cell-array

I am wondering what symbols are typically used to express an empty cell in a matrix. I realize that for each language and software it is different.

For `MatLab`: I've come across `NaN` or `[]` if the matrix is written using cell arrays like so:

```
 >> a{2,2}=[]


a =

 [1] [2]
 [3] []
```

I think in `LaTeX` form, when the rows of elements are listed separated by the `&` symbol you would just use `&(space)&` to indicate an empty cell.

I'm wondering how does `Mathematica` express empty cells in their matrices along with other program used to do calculation on matrices.

I realize that in some cases `0`'s are used to express no connectivity but I'm talking about matrices (or block designs) where connectivity is not relevant and the number 0 doesn't really occur often or in some cases not at all.

I would also like to know what my best option is for empty fields if someone were to send me a covering design for example:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,6
1,2,3,4,7
1,2,3,4,8
```

Where each element is separated by a delimiter (comma in this case). If their block sizes are not uniform, should I just read an empty cell as two commas together?

```
1,2,,4,5
```

Or even a comma + space

```
1,2, ,4,5
```

Also, please correct me if any of these are wrong.

The reason why I would like to know this is because I am trying to create a regex validation expression which only allows matrix forms. Which only permits matrices from all (or as many) languages and softwares.

Comment: If you permit matrix-like entries for as many languages as possible, you can be almost certain you'll get entries which aren't compatible with *any* of those languages because the features are not consistent. This might make your validation pointless.

Comment: @Wolfie I don't know about that. I'm doing very well validating Latex format. With little to no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean the [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null.html) symbol:

> `Null` is a symbol used to indicate the absence of an expression or a result. It is not displayed in ordinary output.
>
> Expressions like `f[e1,,e2]` are interpreted to have `Null` between each pair of adjacent commas.

In lists:

```
{1, , 3} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {1, Null, 3}
> ```

```
{{1,2,,4,5},
{1,2,3,4,6},
{1,2,3,4,7},
{1,2,3,4,8}}//MatrixForm
```

> [image: output]

Relevant Tutorial page: "[Vectors and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VectorsAndMatrices.html)".

Comment: so  should I allow a user to enter Null as an empty cell? Or will they (or their softwares) most likely just use 2 commas? In other words, if somebody uses a program to generate a matrix which has empty cells, what will their output look like for those empty cells? If you can give me all the possibilities you know of that would be great. Also can you clarify whether programs output the Null symbol?

Comment: So that is the output from Mathematica?

Comment: The `Null` is a special [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) which is specific for *Mathematica*. In my answer I show outputs generated by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot! Let me know if you know of any other symbols used by other programs and languages to express empty cells in matrices. Also since you are familiar with Mathematica, can you generate any Johnson graph matrix for me and post your answer here to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808407/what-does-a-matrix-array-look-like-for-a-johnson-graph